Can I make Python interpret {} as set() instead of dict()?
In Python, the literal {} does not represent a set but rather a dict. My main usage of Python is to describe mathematical algebraic structures where sets are fundamental, and I find myself using {} in error frequently. Yesterday, I was debugging a curious bug with my program that resulted from the check if not isinstance(cons, set) triggering due to the empty {} being a dictionary.
I am aware that this request would be a severe undertaking, and an answer to this question would include a serious overview of why this isn't worth it in comparison with getting used to writing set(). However, I have spent quite a few years aware of this difficulty, and I simply can't get myself to stop making this error. Hence, I would prefer an answer to focus on the actual solutions and the associated drawbacks.
Would it be possible in any way to make my installation of Python treat {} as set() instead of dict()?

You can't really change the meaning of {} unless you both compile your own version of python and commit to not using 3rd party libraries. My best recommendation is to get in the habbit of using set() and dict() rather than {}

You are saying that the solution of compiling my own version of python would make the use of 3rd party libraries impossible? That definitely sounds like a deal breaker. I agree with your best recommendation. The question offers context as to why that has been unfeasible.

If you were to compile a custom version of python where empty sqirly braces mean something other than empty dict then you likely could break many 3rd party packages.

If it were me, I'd use a type-checker which lints so that my editor/IDE screams at me when I pass wrong data types around. This saved me hours of debugging in general programming, much more than just in your case of a dict/set mismatch.

I see. It seems an answer explaining the tradeoffs I would be making would more or less settle the question, Jon, if you'd be interested in writing that.

dROOOze, that seems like a very useful tool and would definitely mitigate this issue for me. But I'm not sure how to set something like that up.

@L.E. Regarding type-checkers, if you're using VSCode, I think you just need to add annotations like set[int] in some_variable: set[int] = {}, then Pylance will flag that assignment as having the wrong type.

@wjandrea I see. I do use type annotations, but my IDE doesn't complain when I make the set / dict mistake. I appreciate bringing this to my attention; I will look into it.

All meta commentary should be taken to [Meta].
